# Lines in ggplot with segment function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following script from the DTW package and I'm looking for the equivalent code of this example in ggplot framework:

```
library(dtw)
idx<-seq(0,6.28,len=100);
query<-sin(idx)+runif(100)/10;
reference<-cos(idx)

plot(reference); 
lines(query,col="blue");
alignment<-dtw(query,reference);


#how can I add line on the ggplot plot ?  with geom_segment ?
plot(reference)
lines(query[alignment$index1]~alignment$index2,col="blue")
```

and how to interpret the symbol tilde in this use case in the lines function ?

Comment: Can you add the result to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at it, hope this will help,

```
df <- tibble(
  row_num = 1:100,
  idx = seq(0, 6.28, len = 100),
  query = sin(idx) + runif(100)/10,
  reference = cos(idx)
)
alignment <- with(df, dtw(query, reference))
seg_df <- tibble(
  x = alignment$index2,
  y = df$query[alignment$index1]
)
ggplot(df, aes(row_num, reference)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  geom_path(data = seg_df, aes(x = x, y = y, col = "blue"))
```

**EDIT: for different query and reference**

You can always create different data frame for query and reference as,

```
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(dtw)

query <- tibble(
  row_num = 1:100,
  idx = seq(0, 6.28, len = 100),
  query = sin(idx) + runif(100)/10
)
ref <- tibble(
  row_num = 1:50,
  idx = seq(0, 6.28, len = 50),
  reference = cos(idx)
)
alignment <- dtw(query$query, ref$reference)
seg_df <- tibble(
  x = alignment$index2,
  y = query$query[alignment$index1]
)
plt <- ggplot(ref, aes(row_num, reference)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  geom_path(data = seg_df, aes(x = x, y = y), col = "blue")
plot(plt)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, it works fine for the equal length sequence (query and reference have here length of 100) but but what about the seqences that are not the same  length ?